# Hortonworks Hadoop NN and RM heap stuck overloaded at high utilization, but no applications running? (java.io.IOException: No space left on device)

Tags: hadoop, resourcemanager

Had some recent Spark jobs initiated from a Hadoop (HDP-3.1.0.0) client node that raised some

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: No space left on device

errors and now I see that the NN and RM heap appear stuck at high utilization levels (eg. 80-95%) despite there being to jobs pending or running in the RM/YARN UI.

On the Ambari dashboard I see
[image]

Yet in the RM UI, there appears to be nothing running:
[image]
[image]

The errors that I see reported in most recent Spark jobs that failed are...

```
[2021-02-11 22:05:20,981] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:20 INFO YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 10.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
[2021-02-11 22:05:20,981] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:20 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 10 (csv at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) finished in 8.558 s
[2021-02-11 22:05:20,982] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 7 finished: csv at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0, took 8.561029 s
[2021-02-11 22:05:20,992] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:20 INFO FileFormatWriter: Job null committed.
[2021-02-11 22:05:20,992] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:20 INFO FileFormatWriter: Finished processing stats for job null.
[2021-02-11 22:05:20,994] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 
[2021-02-11 22:05:20,994] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - writing to local FS staging area
[2021-02-11 22:05:20,994] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,455] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,455] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.write(RawLocalFileSystem.java:262)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,455] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:57)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:96)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:68)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:129)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination$TargetFileSystem.writeStreamToFile(CommandWithDestination.java:485)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.copyStreamToTarget(CommandWithDestination.java:407)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.copyFileToTarget(CommandWithDestination.java:342)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPath(CommandWithDestination.java:277)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPath(CommandWithDestination.java:262)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPathInternal(Command.java:367)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPaths(Command.java:331)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPaths(Command.java:352)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.recursePath(Command.java:441)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.recursePath(CommandWithDestination.java:305)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPathInternal(Command.java:369)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,456] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPaths(Command.java:331)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPathArgument(Command.java:304)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPathArgument(CommandWithDestination.java:257)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArgument(Command.java:286)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArguments(Command.java:270)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processArguments(CommandWithDestination.java:228)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.FsCommand.processRawArguments(FsCommand.java:120)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:177)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:328)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:391)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.write(RawLocalFileSystem.java:260)
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,457] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     ... 29 more
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,946] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,946] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,947] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -   File "/home/airflow/projects/hph_etl_airflow/common_prep.py", line 112, in <module>
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,947] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -     assert get.returncode == 0, "ERROR: failed to copy to local dir"
[2021-02-11 22:05:23,947] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - AssertionError: ERROR: failed to copy to local dir
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,034] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,040] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@599cff94{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4041}
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,048] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://airflowetl.ucera.local:4041
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,092] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Interrupting monitor thread
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,106] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,107] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,114] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO SchedulerExtensionServices: Stopping SchedulerExtensionServices
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,114] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - (serviceOption=None,
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,114] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -  services=List(),
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,114] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO -  started=false)
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,115] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,123] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,154] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,155] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,157] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,162] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,173] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,174] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,174] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-f8837f34-d781-4631-b302-06fcf74d5506
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,176] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-57e1dfa3-26e8-490b-b7ca-94bce93e36d7
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,176] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - 21/02/11 22:05:24 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-f8837f34-d781-4631-b302-06fcf74d5506/pyspark-225760d8-f365-49fe-8333-6d0df3cb99bd
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,646] {bash_operator.py:132} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
[2021-02-11 22:05:24,663] {taskinstance.py:1088} ERROR - Bash command failed
```

Note: can't do a lot more debugging, since restarted the cluster via Ambari (need it for certain daily tasks, so couldn't just leave it) and it set the NN and RM heap to 10% and 25% respectively.

Anyone know what could be happening here? Any other place that can (still) be checked for further debugging info?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid this java.io.IOException: No space left on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057474/how-to-avoid-this-java-io-ioexception-no-space-left-on-device) ...while such system administration questions have quite little to do with programming, in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `df -h` and `du -h -d1 /some/paths/of/interest` on the machine doing the Spark calls just taking a guess from the "writing to local FS" and "No space on disk" messages in the errors (running `clush -ab df -h /` across all the hadoop nodes, I could see that the client node initiating the Spark jobs was the only one with high disk utilization), I found that there was only 1GB of disk space remaining on the machine that was calling the Spark jobs (due to other issues) that eventually threw this error for some of them and have since fixed that issue, but not sure if that is related or not (as my understanding is that Spark does the actual processing on other nodes in the cluster).

**I suspect that [this was the problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6092?focusedCommentId=12898371&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-12898371), but if anyone with more experience could explain more what is going wrong under the surface here, that would be very helpful for future debugging and a better actual answer to this post**. Eg.

1. Why would the lack of free disk space on one of the cluster nodes (in this case, a client node) cause the RM heap to *remain* at such a high utilization percentage *even when no jobs were reported running* in the RM UI?
2. Why would the lack of disk space on the local machine affect the Spark jobs (as my understanding is that Spark does the actual processing on other nodes in the cluster)?

If the disk space on the local machine calling the spark jobs was indeed the problem, this question could potentially be marked as a duplicate to the question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18365738/8236733.